# How to add multiple array in Single List using angular 2 typescript

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

I am trying to add multiple array value in single Array.I tried by Concating two array like below

> this.NewsListing = this.NewsListing.concat(this.NewsListing1);

It is concatenate all values but I need to get an values in an List format like.

> {0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, .....}

My Array:
 [image]

Comment: so you want an array of objects as the outcome?

Comment: Yes like an object

Comment: you want an object of objects? not an array?

Comment: yes like that so

Comment: so you want something like this as your outcome? `{0: {<stuffHere>}, 1: {<stuffHere>}, 2: {<stuffHere>}, .....}`?

Comment: yes..this is what i really want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159906/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-girija).

Answer (score 0):

you must use filter extention in typeScript. forEx

```
this.NewsListing = this.NewsListing.concat(this.NewsListing1.filter(c => c.value === someVal));
```

Answer (score 0):

the question does not specify its expected clearly. After reading the comments, this is what I think you want:

```
// first array
let arr1 = [{name:'andy', type:'person'}, {name:'bob', type:'person'}]
// second array
let arr2 = [{name:'cat', type:'person'}]
// concat arr1 and arr2
let arr3 = [ ...arr1, ...arr2]

// convert the array into an object where key is the array index and value is the value of each element in the array
arr3.reduce((prev, current, idx) => {
  prev[idx] = current
  return prev
}, {})
```

To run this ES6 sample, copy & paste to Chrome devtools console.

FWIW, it feels strange that you want this data structure (object with key that represents an array index). Unless it is an API requirement or something you have no control over, you might want to rethink the design/solution.